# Static files not displaying on Google Appengine with Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am [using this guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django) to use Django 'out-of-box' with Google App Engine using Google Cloud SQL.

While most of the application is working fine, the static files (stylesheets and javascripts) are not displaying when I do `dev_appserver.py myapp` though they display fine if I run through `manage.py runserver`

Directly accessing the file shows following error:

```
Page Not Found (404):
Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
^trades/
^login/$ [name='login']
^logout/$ [name='logout']
^admin/
The current URL, static/css/basic.css, didn't match any of these.
```

Please provide any leads.

[P.S. I am using Django version 1.3, python 2.7 and Google Appengine SDK 1.6.3 pre-release (as it supports Django 1.3 with python 2.7).]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide doesn't show how to set up `static_files` (or `static_dir`) in `app.yaml` (which is covered [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html) in the GAE Python documentation). Have you done that?

Comment: Aha, I did not do that. I added following and it worked fine.
`handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: webroot`

But is there anyway to import same automatically from settings.py since the static files location is already mentioned in there?